How to read Gml File in Angular
I don't know how I can read the values of a gml file in angular.
I don't know if there is any library that I can use to read a gml file in angular or a tutorial that explain how to use?
I found this library cytoscape but I don't understand how to use it.
<gml:Polygon>
        <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                 <gml:LinearRing>
                         <gml:coordinates>0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100 0,0</gml:coordinates>
                 </gml:LinearRing>
        </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
</gml:Polygon>

<gml:Point>
        <gml:coordinates>100,200</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Point>

<gml:LineString>
        <gml:coordinates>100,200 150,300</gml:coordinates>
</gml:LineString>

Thank you very much!!!

FileInfo says .gml could either be a "Geography Markup Language" file (GIS/spatial/topological information) or a "GameMaker Language" file (specific game engine). You've tagged [gml] which is the second usage, but you reference "Cytoscape" which is biomedical (neither GIS nor gamedev). Please edit/clarify what you have and what you're trying to do.

Hello what I want is read a gml file like this one gml:Polygon
    <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
             <gml:LinearRing>
                     <gml:coordinates>0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100 0,0</gml:coordinates>
             </gml:LinearRing>
    </gml:outerBoundaryIs>

</gml:Polygon>
gml:Point
    <gml:coordinates>100,200</gml:coordinates>

</gml:Point>
gml:LineString
    <gml:coordinates>100,200 150,300</gml:coordinates>

</gml:LineString>. Maybe is posible only using native javascript
